# React Context Not Updating Globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my Context, But I can't update its values globally. It does change but not globally, and If I refresh the page for example, it goes to the default values again. What I am doing wrong?

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'

const initialState = {
    user: 'magnus',
    isAuth: false
};

const actions = {
    SET_USER: "SET_USER",
    SET_AUTH: "SET_AUTH"
};

const reducer = (state,action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actions.SET_USER:
            return {
                user: action.user
            };
        case actions.SET_AUTH:
            return {
                isAuth: action.setAuth
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const UserContext = React.createContext();

const Provider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    
    const value = {
        user: state.user,
        isAuth: state.isAuth,
        setUser: (user) => {
            dispatch({ type: actions.SET_USER, user});
        },
        setAuth: (auth) => {
            dispatch({type: actions.SET_AUTH, auth});
        }
    };

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );

};

export default UserContext;
export { Provider };
```

Im using this on the other component:

```
const { user, isAuth, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

    return(
        <div>
        <h3>{user}</h3>
        <h3>{isAuth ? 'ok' : 'not ok'}</h3>
        <button onClick={() => setUser('brutus')}>change</button>
        </div>
    )
```

It is updating the user but only in this component, If I reload the page for example, it keeps saying 'magnus' instead of 'brutus'.

This is my index.js:

```
<Provider>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

App.js:

```
<BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you export `UserContext` twice

```js
export const UserContext = React.createContext();

export default UserContext;
```

So just keep the 1st one and import into component:

```
import { UserContext } from './UserContext'
```

Here is the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ybpjyo?file=src/Home.js)

Comment: Didn't change anything. If I change the name in one component and refresh the page in the other one, it resets to the initual values.

Comment: It should not reset to the initial values If i only refresh a component page, right?

Comment: State in context will reset when you refresh the page If you wanna keep the state across page reload you might need to store that in browser storage like localStorage

Comment: Do you have discord?

Comment: @FlokizEZ DM me via noS narT #7316